# memset + whitespace + memcpy

Tags: c, linux, memcpy, memset, c-strings

How can i set a character array say of size 100 to whitespace and then copy 10 charters  to that same string from other.
For example:

there is one char array a[100] 
To do : set all of it to whitespace

Now there is another array  : b[10] (suppose this is filled with some string of length 9) 
To do : copy this array  to the previous one

```
What iam doing is : memset(a, ' ', sizeof(a));
350         memcpy(a,b, strlen(b))
```

But iam  not getting space that i had set after 10 chars has been copied .

Comment: What do you mean with not getting the space?

Comment: If you terminate `a` after the `memset` (like `a[sizeof(a) - 1] = '\0'`) it should work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How do you check your array? Printf?

Comment: You're not doing what you say you are doing. ideone ( http://ideone.com/SmnM9 ) does what you say you are doing without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = NULL;
    char b[10] = "abcdefghi"; /* note that this has a trailing null character */

    a = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    if (a) {
        *(a + LENGTH) = '\0';
        memset(a, ' ', LENGTH);
        fprintf(stdout, "a (before):\t[%s]\n", a);
        memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b) - 1); /* strip trailing null */
        fprintf(stdout, "a (after):\t[%s]\n", a);
        free(a);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running this:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out
a (before):     [...100 spaces...........]
a (after):      [abcdefghi...91 spaces...]                                                                                           ]
```

Comment: `*(a+LENGTH)` should be `a[LENGTH]` - that's what `[]` were meant for.

Comment: `LENGTH[a]` would also be correct. But which is the clearest?

Comment: That's a subjective call that I don't have an opinion about. Pointer arithmetic and array indexing are syntactically correct and, as far as the compiler goes, equivalent in effect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see. Try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    printf("%c", a[i]);
printf("\n");
```

<strike>The reason is when you `memcpy` the string to `a`, a NULL character is placed in `a[10]`. If you only output `a`, the output will stop just before the NULL.</strike>

Comment: Thats actually not correct. Strlen returns the number of characters **without** the null termination character. When his string his ( as mentioned ) 9 characters long, strlen will return also 9. Since the return value of strlen is also his paramter for memcpy, memcpy will also just copie 9 byte. This means the null termination character will NOT be copied!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the null `\0` character at the last position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

don't you think that you need to type cast to `(char *)`

```
a = (char *) malloc(LENGTH + 1);
```